# [SQL]Assign identical Day tag to duplicate rows

Tags: sql

I would like to create an loop query to assign incremental Day tag (Day1, 2,3 etc.) to dates in my table.

*Note. DATEs are sorted by ID, so the first row of each ID (A,B,C...) would be Day1. I wanted to keep the duplicated row as well.

My table:

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1998-1-2 |
| A | 1998-1-2 |
| A | 1998-1-3 |
| A | 1998-1-4 |
| A | 1998-1-6 |
| B | 2012-3-10 |
| B | 2012-3-11 |
| B | 2012-3-13 |

Expected output:

| ID | DATE | Day_tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1998-1-2 | 1 |
| A | 1998-1-2 | 1 |
| A | 1998-1-3 | 2 |
| A | 1998-1-4 | 3 |
| A | 1998-1-6 | 5 |
| B | 2012-3-10 | 1 |
| B | 2012-3-11 | 2 |
| B | 2012-3-13 | 4 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using

Answer (score 0):

the query is:

```sql
SELECT ID, DATE,
       DATE - FIRST_VALUE(DATE)OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) + 1 AS Day_tag
 FROM thetable;
```

works for MySQL and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Date functions are notoriously database dependent.  In some databases `-` is sufficient to get the difference in days.  Other databases have more specialized functions.

In any case, you want the number of days since the minimum date by id.  For that, use `min()` as a window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (date - min(date) over (partition by id)) as date_diff
from t;
```